# Hiding SPAN Overflow

Tags: css

I am trying to create a combobox style widget (jquery-ui compatible) andcurrently I am trying to get the static layout of the box sorted. The problem is when I have long text in the value area of the select it doesn't clip in Firefox (it actually wraps).  I don't want this and tried various combinations overflow:hidden white-space:nowrap etc but in Firefox it still wraps.  The sample code is below.

```
<a href="#" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-custom-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset" style="padding-left:5px;text-decoration: none; width: 139px; ">
    <span style="float:right;margin-top:1px;border-left:1px solid #D3D3D3;" class="ui-custom-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s" ></span>
    <span style="line-height:1.5em;font-size:10px;margin-top:1px;overflow:hidden;height:16px;">If the text is very long then somethin</span>
</a>
```

Can anyone offer any help on this?

Comment: I realise that - I generally use inline styles while on the fly prototying until I am satisified.  It allows me a faster way to manipulate them in Firebug.  But thanks for the constructive feedback :-P

Comment: Check the overflow-wrap css property: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)

Comment: The question & two answers that just keep on giving, 14 years later. Still relevant.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try giving the element a `display:block`, or change the `SPAN` to a block-level element like `DIV`.

Comment: Once again, SO solved a 30 minute problem in all of 5 seconds. +1

Answer (score 21):

The problem is spans are inline elements, and you can't set width or height on inline elements.

And as overflow controls are based on block dimensions It won't work.

However, as of Firefox 3.0, there is support for

```
  display: inline-block
```

Which allows you to control the element as if it *were* a block, but to the containing scope it still behaves like an inline element.

Comment: If you're doing it on the fly in firebug, some things will behave differently in mockup because of reflow. Put it in the stylesheet w/ever and reload the page and sometimes it behaves differently.

Comment: I did throw it into stylesheets and the same result.  I suspect it has to do with classes/attributes assigned further up the stylesheet.  Thanks anyway